# 64-bit CFCalendarComposeAbsoluteTime generated unexpected value

Tags: ios, macos, 64-bit

I used below codes to generate absolute time in a 64-bit app:

```
CFTimeZoneRef cftz = CFTimeZoneCopyDefault();
CFCalendarRef cfgd = CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFGregorianCalendar);

CFCalendarSetTimeZone(cfgd, cftz);
CFAbsoluteTime at = 0.0;

CFCalendarComposeAbsoluteTime(cfgd,
                              &at,
                              "yMdHms",
                              year,
                              month,
                              day,
                              hour,
                              minute,
                              second);
```

Where year, month, day, hour, minute and second were:
   2005, 4, 18, 12, 0, 0.0

But the generated absolute time was not as expected. It turned to 2005-04-19 13:17:27 PDT.

And it would go too far wrong if I added more control, for example, locale.

Any one suffered the same issue before? or know anything about this API?